# How to convert this code from oracle to redshift?

Tags: oracle, amazon-redshift

I am trying to implement the same in redshift and i am finding it little difficult to do that. Since redshift is in top of postgresql engine, if any one can do it in postgresql it would be really helpfull. Basically the code gets the count for previous two month at column level. If there is no count for exact previous month then it gives 0.

This is my code:

```
with abc(dateval,cnt) as(
    select 201908, 100 from dual union
    select 201907, 200 from dual union
    select 201906, 300 from dual union
    select 201904, 600 from dual)
select dateval, cnt, 
       last_value(cnt) over (order by dateval 
                             range between interval '1' month preceding 
                               and interval '1' month preceding ) m1,
       last_value(cnt) over (order by dateval 
                             range between interval '2' month preceding 
                               and interval '2' month preceding ) m2
  from (select to_date(dateval, 'yyyymm') dateval, cnt from abc)
```

I get error in over by clause. I tried to give cast('1 month' as interval) but still its failing. Can someone please help me with this windows function.

expected output:

[image]

Regards

Comment: Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and give us an example of what you've tried in PostgreSQL/Redshift. Thanks.

Comment: Redshifts window functions do not support `RANGE`, so you can only define row-based windows (`ROWS BETWEEN ...`) and that's a bummer. Since you're interested in last 2 months values, I'd create a sequence table with consecutive months, and then `LEFT JOIN` your `abc` table with it using the month to get the contigues date range which will allow you to use row based windows. Then you do `LAG(cnt,1)` and `LAG(cnt,2)` respectively.

Comment: I'll try to give you an example once I'm at my computer

Comment: added the output @botchniaque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it. In Redshift there's no easy way to generate sequences, do I select `row_number()` from an arbitrary table to create a sequence:

```
with abc(dateval,cnt) as(
    select 201908, 100 union
    select 201907, 200 union
    select 201906, 300 union
    select 201904, 600),
     cal(date) as (
         select
             add_months(
                 '20190101'::date,
                 row_number() over () - 1
            ) as date
         from <an arbitrary table to generate a sequence of rows> limit 10
     ),
     with_lag as (
         select
                dateval,
                cnt,
                lag(cnt, 1) over (order by date) as m1,
                lag(cnt, 2) over (order by date) as m2
         from abc right join cal on to_date(dateval, 'YYYYMM') = date
     )
select * from with_lag
where dateval is not null
order by dateval
```

[image]

Comment: This is use-full. just wondering what if there are some other dimensions present and based on that grain prev months will be calculated